# Webform A partially-completed form was found. Please complete the remaining portions

Tags: webforms, status-messages

I'm seeing this message on my webforms:

> A partially-completed form was found. Please complete the
>   remaining portions

How can I suppress this message for Webform version 7.x-4.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is shown if you have the **Show "Save draft" button** option ticked in any webform and is hardcoded into the Webform form builder. If you want to override the message display the [Disable Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) module can help you here.

> Gives a site owner options to disable specific messages shown to end
>   users. The core drupal message system as offered by drupal_set_message
>   is an excellent way for modules to send out messages to the end users.
>   However not all drupal site owners are keen to show all the messages
>   sent out by drupal core and all modules to their users. This module
>   gives site administrators a reasonably powerful way to filter out
>   messages shown to the end users.